# Ctrl+Shift+I in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, eclipse, key-binding

Pressing Ctrl+Shift+I in Windows 7 results in a Tab character being inserted, regardless of the application. Since it conflicts with the default "Inspect" key binding in Eclipse, I would like to remove it. Is it possible?

Comment: Just executed CTRL + SHIFT + I within VS2010/Win7 and was met with the active application's key binding, which is not a Tab char being inserted. Key shortcuts work off the active window and then move upstream if not handled.

Comment: Indeed, the Tab character is not always inserted. In Notepad++, Sticky Notes, Eclipse it is inserted, but in Firefox, Chrome, IE, Skype it does not. This is not the first Eclipse installation where I have this problem. Ctrl+Shift+I has always worked for me in Windows XP, that's why I assumed that Windows 7 was to blame. Can I change this tab-inserting behavior somewhere in the Windows settings?

Comment: I can't get Ctrl+Shift+I to print a tab character in any application.  Do you have a third-party keyboard filter or hotkey program running?

Comment: I'll check, maybe this is some Lenovo/Thinkpad thing. Is there a place where I can see things like this (e.g., the registry, Process Explorer)?

Comment: Looks like the "Inspect" keybinding in Eclipse is not working. I tried changing it, resetting to default, I still can't initiate an inspect from the keyboard. It works with the right-click menu though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I am typing this with Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 64-bit.

Next, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> is not listed as a [keyboard shortcut for Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/126449) (that KB applies to Windows 7).

So I tested it out in Notepad. Sure enough, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> inserted a tab. I came back to Chrome and tried it. On most pages <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> bring up the development tools. In this very text box, it italicized my text.

Odd. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> is a standard italicizing short cut. So I tried <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>, and sure enough italics (good work Stack Exchange Team!). Back in the rest of Chrome, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> appears to do nothing. Back in notepad, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> inserts a tab.

Interesting. Other places to try <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>: The Run dialog (Start -> Run, or <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>). Nothing. Windows Explorer (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>). Nothing as well.

Based on this I don't feel it's a case of Windows conflicting with Eclipse, rather I would suggest checking Eclipse to see if the key binding for <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> is present.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I observe. I checked Eclipse, but I will try again:) After all, I can use another binding, just was wondering if this was easily fixable.

Comment: I also have this annoying problem, but Eclipse doesn't have multiple bindings to this shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+Shift+I , Ctrl+Shift+D **only works in Debug perspective** (Eclipse Neon), otherwise it falls back to some system default binding (TAB) or to nothing.

- So if you don't like switching always the perspective for debugging (like me), use Debug perspective as your default.
- Preferences -> Keys -> **Restore Defaults** migth also be helpful in some cases described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18978159/eclipse-shortcut-keys-are-not-working-suddenly-in-windows).